# How to select all text inside text area of code field on web pages

Tags: webpage, selection

In all the forums web pages the download links are given inside the [code] braces that looks like text area with white background.

When the download links are in large numbers then there are scroll bars.

I find it difficult to scroll up and then select and then drag down to select all links.

Is there any way to select all , when I click on select all on right click then it usually selects the text from whole page not from that code segment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Greasemonkey script called [pre select](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/73497) which allows you to select all text in a <pre> tag by clicking on it. It can easily be modified to work for other tags, including <code>.